# How to use boolean data in DecisionTreeClassifier in sklearn?

Tags: python, data-mining, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I am trying to build a decision tree using python and sklearn DecisionTreeClassifier.

One of the data_type used for splitting the tree  is Boolean(let it be x).However the tree that is generated contains comparisons like x<=0.5 . 
This does not make sense.

Can anybody suggest how to use boolean values in Decision trees.

Comment: x >= 0 and x < 0.5 corresponds to 0. While x >= 0.5 to x <= 1 correspons to 1. In practice, sklearn converts categorical values to continuous values for use in Decision Trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would this not make sense? It tries to create a split with maximal separation between signal and background. Any float >0 and < 1 will result in the same split.